# Preferred Celery Architecture for Identifying Lost Tasks Due to Worker Preemption

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

By default, if I run

```html
my_task = AsyncResult(my_task_id, app=my_app)
print(my_task.status)
```

if the task is either queued in the broker or not found at all, the task status is returned as "PENDING".  This means that there's apparently no way for me to differentiate between tasks that were lost due to a worker being shut down unexpectedly and tasks that are queued in the broker and waiting to run.

I can see several routes forward here, but I'm wondering what the canonical way to deal with task loss is:

1. I could use the app.control.inspect() interface to identify waiting tasks.  Unfortunately, I've tried this and found that app.control.inspect()'s status functions always return None for me.  I can probably figure it out if this is indeed the canonical route.
2. Whenever the client polls for available results, I could check for the task's PENDING status, then revoke() it if it's in a PENDING or failure state and re-queue it.  This works assuming that I've set task_track_started, but feels like a less than ideal solution since revoking and re-queuing a task may interfere with its position in the queue in an undesirable way.
3. In an ideal world, setting task_reject_on_worker_lost would re-queue my tasks on worker loss, but I've found that this is unreliable to the point of uselessness.  I think this is for the same reason that overriding Celery's signals doesn't work for me:  when I lose a worker, I lose it with little or no notice.  There is not a reliable opportunity to execute any code in response to it.
4. I could set both an expiry and a timeout on my tasks, so that a lost task would eventually expire and could be re-queued.  This seems like a very straightforward solution code-wise, but could lead to tasks being endlessly killed and re-queued unnecessarily if there were too many pending tasks at once.

Is it left to the developer to ultimately decide what the correct way to deal with lost tasks is on a case-by-case basis, or is there some canonical best-practices way to deal with tasks lost due to worker preemption?